# Eclipse Juno - why no warning on unused annotated private field?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

In the previous version of Eclipse this works fine.

In Errors/Warnings I checked `"Unused private field" -> Warning`. But it does not seem to work.

For example:

```
public class Main {
    @Resource
    private int a; //I see no warning here
}
```

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F ?

Answer (score 10):

This is intentional see - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365437. Also see an open bug on this topic - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376590

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse Bug Report 386692](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386692) should soon be reopened, to also ignore the @Autowired annotation from the Spring framework.