# How to detect unused private variables with CheckStyle?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, tapestry, checkstyle

When I declare a private variable in my class that is not used, I expect to get a warning.

```
private JavaScriptSupport jsSupport;
// Warning: The value of the field MyClass.jsSupport is not used
```

When I add Apache Tapestry's `@Inject`-Annotation The warning disappears - but why?

```
@Inject
private JavaScriptSupport jsSupport;
// No warning
```

To my understanding, there is no use of unused private variables, even if the get a value injected. Is there a way to define a warning in CheckStyle for this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447910/eclipse-juno-why-no-warning-on-unused-annotated-private-field

Comment: In your case it's a reference type: the injected instance can perform side-effects in its constructor which makes one reason why this should be expected behaviour.

Comment: However, it is possible to to check for unused variables in checkstyle?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: [How to check “The value of the local variable/field is not used” in Checkstyle?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20133122/1005481)